# Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PasteJson.JsonPackage did not load properly

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have visual studio express 2012 
and it was working fine earlier I had run my solution once. But now when I do it, there appears a dialog box with the message!

```
the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PasteJson.JsonPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PasteJson package did not load correctly.
```

the problem may have been  caused by a configuration changhe or by installation of another extension. You can get more information by exmamining the file
 C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VWDExpress\11.0\Log.xml

continue to show this error message?

How do I get rid of this error?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I had this problem as I had an older version of VS2012 Express (release on Web Platform installer dated 15/08/2012).

Try installing 'Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web (Latest)' with release date 22/10/2012 from the Microsoft Web Platform Installer.

That is all I did and I no longer get those messages.

Comment: Thankz for the help Greg! that helped

Comment: This only worked because uninstalling VS2012 removed this folder C:\Users\<your users name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache

Consider just cleaning it. @user_v has the correct answer. :)

http://limzhenghong.wordpress.com/2013/11/10/visual-studio-pastejson-jsonpackage-did-not-load-correctly/

Answer (score 49):

I started to see this on the fresh windows & VS 2013 Ultimate with Update 2 installation.

To resolve the problem, close all Visual Studio instances head over to

`C:\Users\<your users name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache`

and delete all the files in the folder.

It worked fine for me. Thanks to this [article](http://limzhenghong.wordpress.com/2013/11/10/visual-studio-pastejson-jsonpackage-did-not-load-correctly/).

Comment: Just to confirm this works in VS2013, even though I didn't install any extension.

Comment: Saved the day! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Not relevant to VS 2012 express, but I experienced this problem with VS 2013 Premium.  I had recently added the productivity power tools extension.  To get back up and running, I loaded Visual Studio in safe mode:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE>devenv /safemode
```

And un-installed the productivity tools.  The errors went away.

Answer (score 3):

You need to clear the ComponentModelCache folder or rename it.  For Visual Studio 2013, it’s located in the %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0 folder.

Refrence:

http://www.rajapet.com/2014/02/when-the-editorpackage-does-not-load-correctly.html

Answer (score 2):

I had Visual Studio 2013 Professional and I got the same error. I couldn't remove it until I repaired VS installation. It took a while but now it works fine.

Comment: Partial installation of VS2013 Update 4 caused this issue for me. Repair fixed it.

Comment: Even a full installation can cause it if you have the older version of the Azure 2.5 SDK.  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1029189/after-update-4-has-been-installed-such-packages-are-failed-to-load