# XML Parsing Error, running .NET 3.5 application in VS 2013

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I took over a dormant ASP.NET Web Forms project.  The project uses MS SQL Server as its back end -- Enterprise Edition, v10.50 (I think that's 2008); the development environment is a VM of MS Server 2008 R2 hosting both Visual Studio and MS SQL Server.

The first thing I tried to do was run the project.  I get an error page with:

> XML Parsing Error: no element found
>
> Location: http://localhost:{port}/{page}.aspx
>
> Line Number 1, Column 1:

And the HTML source is blank.

On a test system, the project has been properly deployed.

I've looked through the similar questions and Google results.  The typical problem is an unclosed tag in `Web.config` -- I checked for that, and all the tags are properly closed.  What else might be causing this problem?

I think the problem is in my SQL Server connection.  My connection string is:

`<add name="FOO" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLServer2008R2;Initial Catalog=Foobar;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Update: I opened Server Explorer and attempted to expand the database.  I got an error: "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Managment.Sdk.Sfc'.  This issue is discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906686/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-management-sdk-sfc-version-1), and I'll try the solution from that.

Update 2:  That didn't change anything, even once I [cleared the Component Model Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23645994/4995114).

Update 3:  The SQL connection string is most definitely not the problem.  I put in a plain HTML test file, and got the same problem.  Presently the issue appears related to the project targeting the .NET 3.5 platform.  So I have updated the question title.

Comment: Please don't add/remove libraries or clear anything - you'll cause damage when there was none. In fact, nothing at all seems to connect your error page with any faulty connection string. Just debug your application to find what's wrong. Instead of posting the error page, post the actual exception, including its call stack. Add logging to your code to see what is going wrong

Comment: I didn't get anything in the system Application log, nor did I get an exception reported.  I put breakpoints in the page OnPreInit and Page_Load methods, but these didn't get hit.

I agree with you that it's unlikely to be the connection string.  It's more likely to be out of date libraries; when I installed Shared Managment Objects v11, I got a notice that an earlier version was already installed.